# Permitir copiar y pegar números en un textbox de tipo numérico c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Vengo con el siguiente problema, tengo un textbox que solo permite números y poder borrar por obvias razones , pero también me piden que el campo permita realizar la copia y pega de tipo numero para realizar mucho mas rápido el llenado de los datos desde un archivo Excel al formulario en cuestión.

```
      private void TxtRut_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     bool correcto = (e.KeyChar == 'k') || (e.KeyChar == 'K') || (e.KeyChar == (char)8);

     if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back) )
     {
         if (e.Handled = !correcto)
         {
             _ = MessageBox.Show("Solo se Permite el Ingreso de Numeros", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             e.Handled = true;
             return;
         }
         else if (e.Handled == correcto)
         {
         }
     }
 }
```

Y en el evento keydown el codigo que me permitiria el realizar esto, pero al ejecutar me arroja el mensaje de error del evento key press

```
   private bool permitir = true;

 private void TxtRut_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     bool paste = (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyData) == (Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control) | Convert.ToInt32(Keys.V)));
     bool copy = (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyData) == (Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control) | Convert.ToInt32(Keys.C)));
     if (paste || copy)
     {
         permitir = false;
     }
     else
     {
         permitir = true;
     }
 }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Habitualmente veo este tipo de preguntas (en varios lenguajes distintos)...validar, no permitir o formatear un textbox mientras el usuario escribe.  Me parece que esta manera siempre trae más problemas que los que soluciona, sobre todo en winforms que es especialmente malo para esto. Te recomiendo que valides al guardar el formulario o cuando el textbox pierde el foco, que es la manera que trabaja tanto el binding de winforms como el evento validated del textbox

Comment: @Yussef me podrías ayudar dándome un guía por favor?

Answer (score 4):

Concuerdo con **Yussef** en el hecho de que no es buena idea validar los datos que ingresa el usuario mientras este los ingresa. Resulta más práctico validar en momentos puntuales, como al guardar, enviar o perder el foco del campo en cuestión, porque es cuando sabemos (o a veces deducimos) que es cuando el usuario ha finalizado.

Estar validando por cada pulsación de tecla o cambio mínimo puede inclusive ser mucho menos eficiente, en términos de consumo de recursos, que validar una sola vez.

---

No obstante, si tu enfoque requiere si o si un cuadro de texto capaz de validar que, tanto cuando el usuario esté escribiendo, como cuando intente pegar un valor desde una fuente externa, dicho valor sea numérico, entonces, te propongo el siguiente enfoque:

Con ayuda de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113773/9443618) de **bryanbcook** en el sitio en inglés, he diseñado un enfoque que entiendo sería lo que buscas. Se trata de crear tu propio `TextBox`, al que puedes llamar, por ejemplo, `NumericTextBox`:

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
```

Crear una clase hija de `TextBox` nos permitirá hacer dos cosas:

- Invalidar el método `OnKeyDown`:

  ```
  protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      if (!(e.Control                 && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)        // Combinación Ctrl + V
      &&  !(e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0      && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9)       // Teclas numéricas superiores
      &&  !(e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9)  // Teclas de teclado numérico
      &&    e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete  && e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)     // Teclas de borrado (Del) y retroceso (Backspace) 
      {
          e.SuppressKeyPress  = true;
          e.Handled           = true;
          return;
      }

      base.OnKeyDown(e);
  }
  ```

  Para suprimir la pulsación de teclas, gracias a `e.SuppressKeyPress  = true;` y, además, evitar la llamada a `base.OnKeyDown(e)` si el usuario no emplea alguna de tus acciones permitidas:

  ```
  e.Control                 && e.KeyCode == Keys.V       // Ctrl + V
  e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0      && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9      // Teclas numéricas superiores
  e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9 // Teclas de teclado numérico
  e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete  && e.KeyCode != Keys.Back    // Teclas de borrado (Del) y retroceso (Backspace)
  ```

---

- Invalidar el método `WndProc`:

  <sup>Gracias **bryanbcook**</sup>

  ```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
      // Capturamos el mensaje de pegado.
      if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
      {
          // El usuario inició el evento de pegado. Entonces, insertamos el valor
          // directamente desde el portapapeles.
          var value = Clipboard.GetText();

          // Queremos valores puramente numéricos. Para este ejemplo, me decanté por
          // valores enteros, pero podrían ser double, float, decimal, etc.
          // `TryParse` valida que el valor en el portapapeles es un entero. Con `out _`
          // descartamos el valor de salida.
          if (! int.TryParse(value, out _))
          {
              // Si no es entero, evitamos que el control procese el mensaje.
              return;
          }
      }

      base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
  ```

  Para interceptar los mensajes, antes de que sean procesados por el control (`NumericTextBox`). Acá intercepto el mensaje `WM_PASTE`, que es una constante declarada de esta forma:

  ```
  private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
  ```

---

El resultado final sería:

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    // Mensaje que representa la acción de pegado
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Control                 && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)        // Combinación Ctrl + V
        &&  !(e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0      && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9)       // Teclas numéricas superiores
        &&  !(e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9)  // Teclas de teclado numérico
        &&    e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete  && e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)     // Teclas de borrado (Del) y retroceso (Backspace) 
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress  = true;
            e.Handled           = true;
            return;
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Capturamos el mensaje de pegado.
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            // El usuario inició el evento de pegado. Entonces, insertamos el valor
            // directamente desde el portapapeles.
            var value = Clipboard.GetText();

            // Queremos valores puramente numéricos. Para este ejemplo, me decanté por
            // valores enteros, pero podrían ser double, float, decimal, etc.
            // `TryParse` valida que el valor en el portapapeles es un entero. Con `out _`
            // descartamos el valor de salida.
            if (! int.TryParse(value, out _))
            {
                // Si no es entero, evitamos que el control procese el mensaje.
                return;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como te señala en los comentarios, el método de impedir escribir algo que no sea un número en un `textbox` es a lo menos problemático, especialmente en winforms, ya que este framework no cuenta con los mecanismos necesarios (en WPF si es posible). Para lograr este objetivo deberías asignar varios eventos al textbox, lo cual es impráctico, a ti te acaba de pasar!! tenias `keypress` y `keydown`, que ninguno te sirve para el "paste", y así vas a ir acumulando eventos.

En mi opinión, el momento correcto para validar es cuando se quiere guardar en el formulario o cuando el textbox pierde el foco.

Con respecto a esta última forma te daré 2 ejemplos distintos de afrontar el problema.

**1.- Usando el evento `Validated`**

Opcionalmente, podemos usar control `ErrorProvider` para mostrar el error, debes agregarlo al formulario.

El textbox antes de perder el foco irá a este evento, ahí puedes validar que la entrada correspenda a tus necesidades. Adicionalmente puedes establecer `e.Cancel = true;` para impedir que el textbox pierda el foco si hay un error.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Validating += TextBox_Validating;
}

private void TextBox1_Validating(object? sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox? textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if(textBox != null && !int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out var r)){
        e.Cancel = true; // Esto impide perder el foco
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "No es número");
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.Clear();
    }
}
```

---

**2.- Usando Binding**

Acá lo recompendable es crear una clase que sea la representación (el modelo) de tu formulurario. Yo para mantener el ejemplo simple, crearé una propiedad `MyProperty` dentro del mismo form

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",this,"MyProperty",false,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Este método, tiene una mecánica distinta a la anterior. Aquí la validación es automática, ya que la propiedad solo acepta `int` y si la conversión falla retrotrae todo, mostrando el valor anterior en el textbox